# Can't hit same endpoint twice in my Spring-boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman, endpoint

I need to create a kind of compiler that finds and prints first error in a C code. My compiler will be composed of some modules, right now I finished two of them, Lexical Analyzer and Syntactic Analyzer. Lexical Analyzer takes all text and break it in Tokens, tokens being added in a List of tokens. Syntactic Analyzer receives token List and checks that text is written in order: after IF there must be LBAR token, some  expression and RBAR token. Missing one and it will throw a checked error and stop.

```
  @PostMapping("/compile")
    public ResponseEntity<String> setInput(@RequestBody String input){
        if(compile(input)) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Success");
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok("Compile error");
    }

    private boolean compile(String input){
        lexicalAnalyzer = new LexicalAnalyzer(input);
        lexicalAnalyzer.resetCompiler();

        line=1;
        while(lexicalAnalyzer.getNextToken()!=END){ }

        syntacticAnalyzer = new SyntacticAnalyzer(tokens);

        return syntacticAnalyzer.start();
    }
```

Using postman to send a small text in C as String, everything works good until I find first error. For example:

```
int main(){

}
```

returns Success

```
int main({
}
```

returns Compile error and throws "Missing RPAR"

```
int main){
}
```

returns Success, should return Compile error and throw "Missing LBAR". Only if I redeploy I will receive a good response.

Comment: Recompile? You mean redeploy? It looks like you're using some instance variables in the Controller. I'd look for a problem there. Or maybe some static variables in your LexicalAnalyzer or SyntacticAnalyzer. It simply looks like the next request doesn't start with a clean table.

Comment: You are right...I need to initialize my token List in compile method. Sorry for wasting your time and Thanks !

Comment: But the battle is not over. It will still fail when there are multiple requests, because they will be handled in different threads and your Controller is a singleton. So multiple threads will be working on same instances. (This is just an assumption, because I don't see the whole code, but I'm quite sure it will happen).

Comment: There will never be multiple requests.It’s just a school project ment to show us how compilers work.